# Attach function with parameters to dynamically created div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dynamically-generated

I am creating some divs dynamically and Im attaching onclick functions to them.
Is there any way to attach functions which take parameters in this way?

If I just create the div in html I can attach a function and it works perfectly. I can also attach simple functions without parameters dynamically and they work perfectly.

How could I attach this function which takes 'this' as a parameter to my div??

Would anyone have any suggestions???

```
onclick="playSound(this)"

function playSound(el){
var soundId = $(el).html();
if ( soundId == ('d')){
d.playclip()
}
else if ( soundId == ('a')){
a.playclip()
}
else if ( soundId == ('n')){
n.playclip()
}
```

I can attach a function like this and it works fine.

```
$(".myDiv").live("click", function(){
alert('hello');
});
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!!!
Thanks!!

Comment: The last example is missing `()` after `function`

Comment: `soundId == ('d')` is same as `soundId == 'd'`

Answer (score 3):

For this specific case you could use something like:

```
$(".myDiv").click(function(){
  playSound(this);
});
```

---

If you refactor your code dropping `el` and using `this` in this way:

```
function playSound() {
    var soundId = $(this).html();
    if (soundId == ('d')) {
        d.playclip()
    } else if (soundId == ('a')) {
        a.playclip()
    } else if (soundId == ('n')) {
        n.playclip()
    }
}
```

You could use it directly.

```
$(".myDiv").click(playSound);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach some data to your elements using `$(el).data('some-key', 'some-value')` and

```
$(".myDiv").live("click", function() {
   alert($(this).data('some-key'));
})
```

In this way you can attach data to an element and make use of it later.

Answer (score 1):

absolutely. It's called javascript's `bind` function:

```
playSound.bind(this, arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Another useful function that is similar is jquery's proxy function. This only keeps track of the scope though and doesn't allow you to send other parameters:

```
$.proxy(playSound, this)
```

Comment: The stuff about `.bind()` is correct, but it's not a jQuery feature. It's native JavaScript.  There's a somewhat similar jQuery feature called `$.proxy()` however.